# If a simulacrum uses magic jar to control a new body can the new body regain hp by mundane healing?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, healing, simulacrum

After a simulacrum uses [*magic jar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-jar) to gain control of a new body, can that new body regain hit points normally? Or is the new body still restricted by the simulacrum's healing restrictions?

Comment: A simulacra is an "Illusory Duplicate." Does it...even _have_ a soul to shove in a magic jar?

Comment: In the spell description is also stated that simulacrum is a creature

Comment: I would also be interested in this topic, @guildsbounty. Obviously, mechanically a simulacrum is perfectly capable of casting magic jar and then possessing another body, but does this just mean that its soul is a copy of yours? I'm picturing a simulacrum that goes evil, and tries to possess the original body, in order to be the real one. You know what? I'll ask this question.

Comment: It can be evil (as the caster), but still "... It obeys your spoken commands, moving and acting in accordance with your wishes ..."

Comment: Related: [Does a simulacrum's have a soul?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115682/28591)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### A simulacrum can restore HP in the possessed body.

When Magic Jar is cast, the simulacrum's soul enters the new body changing all of its statistics including HP except for mental ability scores and it retains class features.

> ... game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the creature though you retain your alignment and your Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores. You retain the benefit of your own class features.

The original simulacrum body does not regain any hit points; it is "formed from ice and snow" and requires expensive material components to repair.

Comment: It would be strange in that case since it would still be valid that " you can **repair** it in an alchemical laboratory, using rare herbs and minerals since **the host body  is different by his body** " but it could be no more "partially real and formed from ice or snow" but  made of meat (depends on the host body choosen).  Is this still what you think?

Comment: Have you considered the Simulacrum taking over a body that has a fast healing feature?

Comment: If the regeneration is due to the class feature of the host body it would not apply to the body under the control of the simulacrum

Comment: @Earthling My answer states that the original body can be repaired. The possessed body cannot since the repairing of the simulacrum is not tied to mental ability scores or class features.

Comment: OK, then if the host body is damaged It should be possible heal it, and should be healed also by a long rest

Comment: @Earthling There is no restriction on healing the host body as it does not carry the limitation the simulacrum has.

Comment: You should change your bolded statement to 'Yes' or some variety thereof; at present it reads like the simulacrum *can't* regain hp in the new form, while obviously it *can*, it's just that that hp doesn't normally come back to it's original body.

Comment: It seems not clear if simulacrum can cast the spell to begin with, [as it is not clear if it has a soul to transfer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/115688/75095)